# What is the best to use between Java ScheduledExecutorService and Quartz Scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService to execute bulk email shooting. What difference will it make if I replace it with QuartzScheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about QuartzScheduler's pros here: -> http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features. I use QuartzScheduler rather than ScheduledExecutorService because it helps me with my transactions. It's my favorite when it comes to scheduling regular jobs. I set triggers using annotations, meaning I have less XML to deal with (not a fan of XML). I have something like:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 1/1 * ? *")
public void run() {
    //what your run method will do 
}
```

There's no need to figure out how to write your cron expressions, you can just have them made here: -> http://www.cronmaker.com/.

However, with ScheduledExecutorService you won't have to download any library and it is supposed to handle an unlimited number of tasks. Since it's part of Java  APIs, you can find tons of tutorials online, probably exactly on what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Andreea, I am worried about the performance and load on the App server. No doubt both have different areas of functionality but can be used for doing repetitive task. Which can be yield better performance?

Comment: I would definitely recommend QuartzScheduler, when it comes to performance, I'm working with it right now and it's exactly what I need. I have tasks that execute 2-3 times per day, tasks that only run weekly, monthly (and so on) and I store information about them into the DB. I'm content with what  QuartzScheduler can do. It works great with my Tomcat server. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the info.. :)

Comment: My pleasure, please rate the answer if it was useful :)